# How to dynamically iterate tags attribute with Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks

Let's say I have a desc.json file that looks as following:

```
{"descr":
 [
    {
       "class":"foo1",
       "name":"bar1",
       "pattern": "^[ 0-9]+$"
    },
    {
       "class": "foo2",
       "name": "bar2"
    }
 ]
}
```

and data.json file that looks as following:

```
{"data":
 {
    "bar1": "1925",
    "bar2": "18"
 }
}
```

In order to render an html as following:

```
<input class="foo1" value=1925 name="bar1" pattern = "^[ 0-9]+$">
<input class="foo2" value="18" name="bar2">
```

Using Nunjucks, could someone provide an example?

Thanks

Comment: _desc.json_ is invalid at-least use correct pseudo data

Comment: okey, i've edit my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.render(#template, {descr, data});
...

{% for e in descr %}
<input class="{{e.class}}" value="{{e.name and data[e.name] or ''}}" name="{{e.name}}" pattern = "{{e.pattern}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes this answer seems quite right BUT has a major problem that is: what woul the result html string look like when your `e.class` or `e.name` is `undefined`? Would it not break apart all your html string?  In PUG you can just write `p&attributes(e)` or something like that and end of the question. Can Nunjucks do as simple as that?

Comment: If `class` is a not define for `e` then by default nunjucks set it to empty string. If you want to avoid empty values then you can use next wrapper `{{'class="' + e.class + '"' if e.class}}`.

Comment: I used something like this because I had the double quotes escaped: `{{ ('class="' + item["class"] + '"')|safe if item["class"] }}`